# 0 jobs in <your country>

Tags: discussion, jobs

I just took the annual survey and one of the questions inspired me to make this post. I take a look at the Careers site once in a while, but unfortunately most of the times I see this:

> 0 jobs in Belgium

Regular job board suck, often the formatting is horrible and half of them don't even include the programming language being used. So I'd love to be able to use the Careers site.

Does SE do any promotion to attract employers, or is there a way for us users to help make it more popular?

Comment: Jah, in de West-Vlonders zitt'n d'r ni viel mensche die programmeurs ahwerve, njee. (Haha, just kidding guys. This is the kind of language they speak in his region.)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Makes you think Belgians were the ones pressing for raw string literals...

Comment: Might it make sense to search across borders in such a case?

Comment: @Pëkka In my case I could take a look at the Netherlands (same language) just across the border, but there are plenty of jobs in my region, they're just not on Careers, I don't think many people know of the site here. I'd also feel weird about relocating for a job, a lot of people here would consider it exceptional to move to a place more than 30 miles away from your parent's house. Cultural thing, I guess.

Comment: @Stijn: I'm facing the same doubts. Fat chance though I'll end up moving (salaries seem to be pretty low compared to the rest of the world), either to a bigger European hub (UK/Netherlands/Germany) or the USA. If there would be just some activity in Belgian job postings it would already help a lot.

Comment: Interesting to mention that Israel, half the population of Belgium, does have [some jobs on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Israel&range=100). Anyway back on topic, I think that in such case the whole section should be hidden, no point having such thing empty.

Answer (score 5):

Dev on the Careers team here. I definitely agree with you about the shortcomings of other job boards for programmers - in many ways, that's why we're doing what we're doing.

Yes, we do actively recruit employers for Careers. The two major geographic regions that we've targeted so far are the US and the UK, and we have a significant presence in France and Germany. As you can imagine, we've got a number of other locations on our road map that we're working to expand into.

That being said, in terms of what you can do to help us: spread the word. The employers on Careers are very responsive to the fact that we have some of the best developers in the world as part of the SO community, but there isn't quite the jump from SO into Careers or vice-versa yet. As I mentioned, we do plan on expanding into other regions, but running parallel to that, if employers hear about devs talking about Careers, they will want to come to Careers too.

Personally, getting the developer community more actively involved in Careers is something that I'm very interested in. I'd like to see more ways on the platform to help you help us.